# sort dataframe with user defined sequence in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame and I wanted it to be sorted with 2 columns: type and name. Both are strings. However for type, I wanted it to be ordered as Cape, Supramax, Handysize, but the default sorting is to sort alphabetically, is there a way to sort it with my desired sequence?

```
>>> db[['VESSELTYPE','VESSELNAME']].head(10)
  VESSELTYPE        VESSELNAME
0  Handysize      AS
1   Supramax      AK
2   Supramax      AK
3   Supramax      AM
4   Supramax      AM
5   Supramax      BS
6       Cape      BA
7  Handysize      CA
8       Cape      CD
9  Handysize      CT
```

This only sorts alphabetically, i.e. Cape first, then Handysize, then Supramax:

```
db.sort(['VESSELTYPE', 'VESSELNAME'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the dataframe into list of tuples

```
subset = data_set[['data_date', 'data_1', 'data_2']]
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]
```

have a global hash, depending on your order

```
ENUM_VALUE = { 'Cape':1, 'Supramax':2, 'Handysize':3 }

sorted(tuples, key=lambda (k,v): ENUM_VALUE[k] )
```

Comment: Thanks but how to sort the whole data frame at once?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try converting dataframe - > tuples and sort them.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found a way to solve it, tho not that "elegant":

```
db['sorting'] = db['VESSELTYPE'].apply(lambda x: {'Cape':1,'Supramax':2,'Handysize':3}[x])
db = db.sort(['sorting','VESSELNAME'])
db = db.drop('sorting',1)
```

The idea is to convert char into integers so that it will be sorted in df.sort()